# REST not returning any value if other than english language

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

Rest URLs are not returning any value if I pass other than English language in IE, it is working fine in Chrome but not in IE. Need help to get this working in IE. Below is REST call

`/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items?$select=*&$filter=substringof('银行存款1',ChineseLang)`

Comment: you should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution for this, In chrome parameter is getting encoded that why it was able to fetch the record from list. For IE browser is not encoding the value so we need to encode the values.

```
myAngApp1=document.getElementById("ItemSearch");
var uri = myAngApp1.value;
var place = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

Pass Place in the parameter in REST call.

Thanks
Sanjeev Gautam